# Inserting a symbol between the two arrows of \rightrightarrows

Tags: arrows, stacking-symbols, substack

I am trying to insert a vertical symbol `\leqslant` between the two arrows of `\rightrightarrows` as in the picture below

[image]

obtained with the following awkward code. What would be the right way to do it?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand{\vleq}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{-90}{$\leqslant$}}

\begin{document}

\[
  X \overset{g}{\underset{f}\rightrightarrows} Y  
\]
\[
  X \enspace
  \substack{
    g \\
    \longrightarrow \vspace{-0.5mm}\\ 
    \tiny{\vleq}\vspace{-0.5mm}\\
    \longrightarrow \\ 
    f
  }
  \enspace Y  
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Inside math mode, in order to use a different (smaller) font, you could/should use \scriptstyle or \scriptscriptstyle. Hence delete \tiny. What is awkward about your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this? I build the alignment the hard way.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,graphicx}

\newcommand{\smallrotleq}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{-90}{\tiny$\leqslant$}}
\newcommand{\smallrotgeq}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{-90}{\tiny$\geqslant$}}

\newcommand{\arrowstack}[3]{%
  % #1 = top, #2 = middle, #3 = bottom
  \mathrel{%
    \mathop{%
      \sbox0{\hbox{$\vcenter{%
        \offinterlineskip
        \ialign{%
          \hfil##\hfil\cr
          $\longrightarrow$\cr
          \noalign{\kern-0.25ex}
          #2\cr
          $\longrightarrow$\cr
        }%
      }$}}%
      \dp0=\dimexpr\dp0-0.5ex\relax\box0
    }\limits^{#1}_{#3}%
  }%
}

\begin{document}

\[
X \arrowstack{g}{\smallrotleq}{f} Y \arrowstack{f}{\smallrotgeq}{g} Z
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

A couple of corrections are necessary because of the peculiar bounding box of the arrows. With different math fonts it's possible that a fix is necessary.

Comment: Nice answer, as usual !